# Android, How to retrieve the image previously save and display when required

Tags: android, android-imageview, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I used this code below to save an image taken from the camera intent, to a folder in the gallery, which worked great. I'd like to retrieve the image to display on an ImageView within an activity when asked, though after trying various methods/code, nothing so far has worked. Given the path/code used to save the image, could someone point me in the right direction of how to get it back. Thanks in advance - Jim.

```
public void SaveImage(Context context,Bitmap ImageToSave, String fileName){ 
    TheThis = context; 
    String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ NameOfFolder; 
   // String CurrentDateAndTime= getCurrentDateAndTime(); 
    File dir = new File(file_path); 

    if(!dir.exists()){ 
        dir.mkdirs(); 
    } 

    File file = new File(dir, fileName + ".jpg"); 

    try { 
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file); 
        ImageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut); 
        fOut.flush(); 
        fOut.close(); 
        MakeSureFileWasCreatedThenMakeAvabile(file); 
        AbleToSave(); 

    }  
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {UnableToSave();} 
    catch (IOException e){UnableToSave();}        

} 

private void MakeSureFileWasCreatedThenMakeAvabile(File file) { 
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(TheThis, 
            new String[] { file.toString() }, null, 
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() { 
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) { 
            Log.e("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":"); 
            Log.e("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri); 

        } 
    }); 

}
```

Comment: you can save the image on sd card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a proper path and permissions, here is the code working perfectly for me

```
File rootsd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String rootPath = rootsd.getAbsolutePath();
String pathName = rootPath + "your path here" + "image name here"; 
try {           
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);
layout.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Comment: Hi Marko, thanks for the quick reply. Impressed! I'm trying this code now, though I don't have the method setBackgroundDrawable(). I'll search this method then try again. Let you know when it works. Thanks Jim

Comment: I'm still missing something, it may be a permission I suspect. I've got the permission <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> to I can save to the folder, but do I need one to retrieve, and if so could you tell me what it is? Thanks again

Comment: You are not missing any permissions, this is the only one needed. Are you getting any exceptions? Are you absolutely sure you are passing right path? Otherwise you need to pass your code in order to be helped.
Best of luck

Comment: Other than the setBackgroundDrawable() method missing, there was no errors. Instead of this method I used this code Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
   ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
  myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

Comment: (...Pressed enter too quickly there), Even with the new code, there's no errors, though the image doesn't appear. The "path" and "image name" I entered were the folder and image name I used to save it"/WhatsItWorth" for the folder name and "photoThree.jpg" for the image name. Could my path name be missing something? Also would this Bitmap code work in place of setbackgrounddrawable? Cheers again

Comment: try
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4); myImage.setImageDrawable(d);
You can also set a bitmap as you tried but I still think you have some other issues.
Also ImageView has setBackgroundDrawable, but for this View it is better to set source ImageDrawable

Comment: Thanks again for your time on this one. I reckon you're right, there's probably other things that are missing which is stopping this code from working. I tried the change, but still no joy. When I finally get it solved, I'll post it here. Cheers again Jim

Comment: Thanks again Marko. Managed to solve it, All I needed to do with put the forward slash / in front of the image name. Cheers for all your help, A well deserved +1.